# Saving Images as Binary Data in Core Data - Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

The following code successfully saves `Car` entities to `Core Data`. As you can see the `Car` entity has an attribute of `Binary Data` where I'm saving an image to use it as a thumbnail.  My issue with the code below is that if the user decides not to add an image to some of the `Car`s, I need to provide a default image, the only option that I can think of is to have a `defaultCarImage` in the `Assets` folder then call it and save it for cars where the user didn't select an image for. My problem with this approach is that if the user decides not to use images for any of hes/hers cars I will be saving the same image in dozens or hundreds of cars. Is there a way to somehow reuse an image that is already saved in `Core Data`?

What is the right approach to provide a default image for `Car` entities where the user didn't provide an image?

### ENTITY

```
Car
```

### Attribute

```
carImage    Binary Data (Allows External Storage)
make        String
model       String
```

### Core Data Manager

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager{
    static let instance = CoreDataManager()
    
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext
    
    init(){
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print("Error loading Core Data. \(error)")
            }
        }
        context = container.viewContext
    }
    
    func save(){
        do{
            try context.save()
            print("Saved successfully!")
        }catch let error{
            print("Error saving Core Data. \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

### Core Data Model

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    let manager = CoreDataManager.instance
    
    @Published var cars: [Car] = []

    func addCar(make: String, model: String, image:UIImage){
        
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1)
        
        let car = Car(context: manager.context)
        car.make = make
        car.model = model
        car.carImage = imageData
        save()
        getCars()
    }
}
```

### Content View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()
    @State private var makeInput:String = ""
    @State private var modelInput:String = ""
    @State private var carImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if let inputImage = carImageFromPicker {
                Image(uiImage: inputImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // show camera
                    }
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "car.fill")// default image 
                .onTapGesture {
                    // show camera
                }
            }

            Button(action: {
                saveNewCar()
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }

    func saveNewCar(){
        coreDataViewModel.addCar(make: makeInput, model: modelInput, image: carImageFromPicker!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code will only save the image selected from the image picker (maybe some code is missing) so keep it that way and make the image property optional. Then you can use the single default image whenever a car’s image property is nil

Comment: I made the `carImage` optional in Core Data.  So now, for the objects without an image do I just provide an empty `Data()` or `Data(count:0)` to Core Data?  Again, what I'm trying to avoid is to save the same image multiple times in Core Data.

Comment: I think I got it. After making the `carImage` optional in Core Data I'm providing an empty `Data()` for objects without images and using a `defaultImage` from the Assets folder for visuals purposes only. Thanks for pointing out the fact that the Binary Data could be optional.

Comment: If the property is optional then you don't need the `Data()`. Leave the property alone and it will be nil. Or set it to nil to make it clear if you prefer.